# Gnome Terminal window is stuck on top but not really there

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gdm

There is a terminal left floating on top of my other windows:

[image]

It doesn't show if I take a window screenshot.

[image]

I can't <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Drag - that drags the window below. I can't <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> - Terminal is not open:

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the run dialouge, and running the command `r` fixed the issue:

[image]